# Find the derivatives of arbitrary order of a function found using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, function-construction

For the following initial value problem

```
BC[b_]:=x[0]==b;
eq[b_]:=NDSolve[{equation==0, BC[b]}, x, {t,0,1000}];
body[t_,b_]:= x[t]/.eq[b];
```

one could define the derivative of `body` with regard to `t` as

```
Dbody[t_,b_]:=x'[t]/.eq[b];
```

However I'm trying to find a way to define this for derivatives of arbitrary order  with regard to `t`, and make the definition of `Dbody` redundant. Simple invocations of `'`, `D` and `Derivative` failed; for example:

```
Derivative[1][body][1,1]
```

returns

```
body'[1,1]
```

Comment: @m_goldberg: The title does not correspond to what I'm asking. I already get derivatives of arbitrary order wrt `t` if the initial conditions are constant. It is the case of two variables that I haven't been able to find.

Comment: `eq[b_] := NDSolve[{x'[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == b}, x, {t, 0, 1}][[1]]` and  `x'[1/2] /. eq[2]` works?

Comment: @auxsvr. Your original title didn't correspond to your real question. I did my best to fix it. If you don't like what I did, re-edit it, but try to make it clearer this time.

Comment: @chris, it works, but it is not exactly what I want. Do you have any idea how to wrap this in a function of `{t,b}`, so that taking derivatives of it wrt `t` returns the correct result?

Comment: does this do what you want ? `f[t1_, c_] := Module[{eq},
  eq[b_] := NDSolve[{x'[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == b}, x, {t, 0, 1}][[1]];
  x'[t1] /. eq[c]]`; `f[1/2, 2]`

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use the [`` StateData` `` framework of `NDSolve[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html) for the purpose. I'll give a sketch on how one might go about it, and leave the encapsulation as a complete routine to you.

Start with an initial state:

```
$state = First @ NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{\[FormalX]'[t] + \[FormalX][t] == 0,
                                           \[FormalX][0] == 1}, \[FormalX], t];
```

(I have chosen the function name to be a [formal symbol](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264) for safety.)

Whenever you need to propagate your solution, you only need to call `` NDSolve`Iterate[] ``:

```
NDSolve`Iterate[$state, 5]
```

After propagation (one can go either forward or backward, depending on the need), a call to `` NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[] `` yields an `InterpolatingFunction[]` object...

```
sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[$state]
   {\[FormalX] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 3.}}, <>]}
```

...which can now be used for evaluation:

```
{\[FormalX][2], \[FormalX]'''[3]} /. sol
   {0.135335, -0.0526585}
```

Why go through all that trouble of using state data, you ask? That's because changing initial conditions is a snap with this framework, by virtue of the function `` NDSolve`Reinitialize[] ``:

```
$state = First[NDSolve`Reinitialize[$state, \[FormalX][0] == -3/2]];
```

from which you can propagate and evaluate once more:

```
NDSolve`Iterate[$state, 5];
    sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[$state];
{\[FormalX][2/3], \[FormalX]''[5/2]} /. sol
   {-0.770126, -0.122977}
```

The gist of it then, is to maintain a state of your DE, propagate if needed before evaluating, and use `` NDSolve`Reinitialize[] `` whenever you need to change initial conditions.